# UrlFetch Status code 200 OK but response showing 'unsupported browser'

Tags: google-apps-script, user-agent, urlfetch, siteminder

I have setup a daily trigger for the below function to login using Basic Authentication to my company provided url and download a JSON response into a Google Spreadsheet. Later i will parse this response into a spreadsheet table.

The Response code is coming as 200 OK, but the response text shows ERROR and has **'unsupported-Browser'** mentioned in the returned html response.

```
function test1(){
  var url = "https://some.website.com/path1/path2/path3/";
  var user = 'test123@test.com';
  var pwd = 'mypass123';

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    'headers': {
      'SMAGENTNAME' : '-SM-uL9Ydk9ZgPvYi+geshsOjQi7kbevUvOTmZvMksmphUle4s7h0Mx4uhOXXq/8JSBQ06Y',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pwd, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)
    }
    });      
  Logger.log(res.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log(res.getContentText());
}
```

I am getting the following html response:

```
    ...</head>

<body ng-init="errorMessage=''; errorTitle='ERROR'; appName='ABC'; browserLocale='null'; requireCorpCred=false;downTimeNotificationSvc=''; targetUrl='https://abc.something.xxx.com/portal/site/something'; userNameType='text'; passwordType='text'; ">
    <div ng-controller="LoginController as vm" class="login-background container-fluid" data-ng-cloak>
        <xxx-cookie-policy></xxx-cookie-policy>
        <div class="row auth-body" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{vm.backgroundImg}})'}">
            <xxx-unsupported-browser></xxx-unsupported-browser>
            <div class="auth-section col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-11 col-xs-12">
                <a class="help" data-ng-click="vm.gotoSupportPage()">
                    <i class="xxx-icon xxx-icon-help"></i>
                </a>.......
```

I found online that some servers only allow recognized browsers. Our company site uses SiteMinder authentication layer. I guess Google Appsscript is not recognized as a browser and it also does not allow customization or spoofing of its **User-Agent**.

Is there a workaround to download the response?

Comment: Sure, contact the company whose website you are scraping, and ask them which methods they allow for programmatic access to their site's content. Odds are you will get an API endpoint which serves you structured data (like JSON), and they no longer have to serve a full browser page to a robot.

Comment: @tehhowch i am not scraping any website as you presume. I am downloading data for reporting purposes using my company user authentication as you can see from the code.

Comment: Then it seems like you need to contact SiteMinder support, since you are their customer!

Comment: Did you tried sending same request with postman or something like that ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `User-Agent` key to `headers`?

Comment: Yes @Kos, but it doesn't work! Google doesn't allow changing it's User-Agent that it passes. Also there is no such parameter in [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). See `Advanced Parameters`.

Comment: @sifar786 probably it should be inside advanved parameter named `headers`, but documentation doesn't reveal all supported headers

Comment: @Kos, i checked...no luck yet!...

Comment: @Umair yes, i am able to download the JSON using `Postman` as well as `Insomnia`.